# Verifying a person's age

Tags: java, validation, constructor

When coding I noticed I started to get into a habit of not using if-else statements when the else block only has one line of code. For example, if I have code that can be solved like this:

```
public Person(int initialAge) {
    if(initialAge < 0){
        System.out.println("Age is not valid, setting age to 0.");
        age = 0;
    }
    else{
        age = initialAge;
    }
   }
```

I will instead remove the `else` statement entirely to cut down on a few lines of code. This results in my code looking more like this:

```
public Person(int initialAge) {
    age = initialAge;
    if(initialAge < 0){
        System.out.println("Age is not valid, setting age to 0.");
        age = 0;
    }
   }
```

I'm wondering if this is a bad coding habit to get into and if I should break out of this coding habit or if it'll be fine to continue doing this. Would doing this be a bigger issue down the line when I get onto more complex programs?

**Edit:** Just wanted to give some more information for why part of the code is written the way it is. The snippet provided is part of a coding challenge where one of the requirements is to set any negative number inputted to 0.

Comment: Yes, it is a bad habit because it makes your code harder to understand (both for others and yourself in the future when you look back at your code). if-else is very straight forward; this however, is not.

Comment: Not only is it harder to read, it also isn't semantically useful. First setting the age to a possibly negative value, and then changing it back to zero. Should be done in one step, as is done in the first example.

Comment: When it comes down to complex type of conditions, you may have to use the else without a choice. Cutting down lines of code could make your program effective but then at times it could be complex as well.

Comment: In your particular case the if-else set up is better.  However it almost seems that you should be throwing an exception rather than setting it to 0

Comment: Whats making this hard to understand is that you are using initialAge to set age before checking its value.

Comment: it depends upon situation...what if you have a long block of code that was supposed to be managed within else? your code becomes messier...as else is ment to handle unless otherwise

Comment: also why wouldn't you declare age as an unsigned if negatives are not allowed?

Comment: @AhmedMasud Does Java have unsigned ints?

Comment: @Gendarme ah right *java* ... Well java 8 does.

Comment: @AhmedMasud Java 8 has methods that use ints *as if* they were unsigned. But you cannot declare a primitive that by itself *is* unsigned. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25556017/1310566

Comment: What sort of object is `age` and how does it respond to assignment?  If it's not a primitive type you may have unexpected problems.

Comment: The second possibility is not be valid if `age` is `final`, so it may not be a viable option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You should throw exceptions in case of invalid values. As suggested by Simon Forsberg you can throw `IllegalArgumentException` or you can make your user-defined exception if you want to customise it.
2. You should completely avoid this habit because in the question provided, you have a simple piece of code, but there are areas where you deal with complex data structures and values/database interactions. If you keep following this habit, someday you will initialise the value to be returned before checking things and later on get trapped by exceptions that you might not have thought could occur.

Answer (score 39):

The biggest problem I see here is that you are printing a warning message to `System.out` and then using a default value for something which sounds like an *Exception*.

Why allow negative values at all?

```
if (initialAge < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Initial age cannot be negative, was specified as " + initialAge);
}
age = initialAge;
```

This way it is always up to the caller to **pass a valid age** instead of the method defaulting to zero which will bring other problems. It is better to have your program break early because of a bug than to have a warning message be printed out which *may* indicate a bug.

Comment: Side note: If you absolutely *must* choose between your options. Go with the if-else. I am not mentioning that in my answer because I don't believe that is the right approach. The right approach is to let the caller determine the default value if for some weird reason it is negative.

Comment: *Age is not valid, setting age to 0* And that 0 is not even a valid age either

Comment: @HankyPanky if you're newly born, it could be.

Comment: Hello @SimonForsberg, Appreciate the response!

The snippet I provided is part of my submission to a coding challenge. One of the requirements was to set any negative number inputted to 0.

Comment: @RussWilkie That can still be done outside the `Person` constructor.

Answer (score 4):

You put the main functionality *before* the input verification. Either verify *first*

```
if(!foo) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("not foo");
}
doStuff();
```

or use an if-else with the main functionality first

```
if(foo) {
  doStuff();
} else {
  handleWrongFoo();
}
```

The ugliest part of your solution, to me, is doing something invalid, then going "no, wait".

```
do {
  doStuff();
} ormaybeif(!foo) {
  handleWrongFoo();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, you should probably throw an exception here.  A minor style point, is that if possible I usually put the main flow of the program in the `if` part with non-standard processing in the `else` part.

In this case, either:

```
if (initialAge >= 0) {
  age = initialAge;
} else {
   System.out.println("Age is not valid, setting age to 0.");
   age = 0;
}
```

or:

```
if (initialAge >= 0) {
  age = initialAge;
} else {
  throw new InvalidParameterException("Person(): invalid parameter. initialAge = " + initialAge)
}
```

I also prefer `if (...)` with a space between the `if` and the opening parenthesis.  This helps distinguish `if`, `when` and other language statements from method calls, where there is no space.

Comment: which statement that goes where (normal case first vs. edge case first) is a bit opinion-based. The positive thing about throwing an exception in the normal if is that then you wouldn't need an `else`

Comment: putting the main flow in `if` prevent from using `elseif`. I usually go like `if(wrong){throw new Exception1} elseif(also_wrong){throw new Exception2} else{everything="OK"}`

Comment: How about: `if (OK) { doNormal(); } else if (wrongType1) { throw new Type1Exception(); } else { throw new OtherTypeException(); }`.  Not a major point, more a matter of style.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the situation but for the situation mentioned in your code not only it reduce performance but also it decrease your code readability. Performance issue is because of setting a variable two times in some cases. And as a code reader I wonder why you change a set variable again(For code readability).

Comment: I'd say that the performance issue is not really an issue, that's quite irrelevant.

Comment: @SimonForsberg Hey simon, your response intrigues me. Why would performance not be an issue? Is this mainly because of the outlying issue in my example outweighs any performance issue(s) or would performance also not be relevant for similar coding examples?

Comment: @RussWilkie It's because computers are so fast you will barely be able to tell the difference. Maybe if you do it a billion times you *might* have saved a few milliseconds. No matter if you set the value once or twice, it is still very cheap constant-time operation.

Answer (score 1):

I still use a no-else structure and find it cleaner than the conventional if/else for selected cases.  This example doesn't avoid the else, of course, but it does illustrate the ordering I use:  default, good case, fail case.

```
function Person(int initialAge) 
{
    age = 0 ; // initialise to the default value

    if (initialAge > 0)    // if passed a good value
    {
        age = initialAge ; // use it 
    }
    else  // but if passed-in value not good, complain
    {
        System.out.println("Supplied age not valid, age set to 0.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have already pointed out the flaws in this coding habit, however, there is an upside to it. If performance is important to you then this is supposedly a good coding practice.

Modern processors does a lot of prediction to help optimize execution. Every branch you add makes this prediction harder or impossible, which harms performance. An if-statement is one branch, the else-statement is another. If you skip the else-statement and preemptively do what you would otherwise do inside the else-statement before the if-statement then this will make prediction easier for the processor, thus improving performance. Of course, it depends on how expensive the operations inside the else-statements are. As long as it's just assigning values to a few variables then it's fine.

Source: My teacher in the Optimization course at The Game Assembly, where I study Game Programming.

I know some programmers will scoff at these kinds of "micro optimizations" as being unnecessary or pointless, but performance is very important in game development. If this piece of code is going to run thousands of times each frame then it is well worth doing this kind of optimization.

Edit: The performance gain *might* be affected by what language you're coding in. This course was held in C++, which is widely used in game development for having great performance.

Answer (score -1):

I would agree that this is a bad habbit althoug I always try to find alternatives to an if-else-statement.

My first attempt would be:

```
class Person {
    private final int age;

    /**
     *  Creates a new person with age 0.
     */
    Person() {
        age = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new person with age
     * @param age the age of the person. Must be <code>>0</code>
     */
    Person(int age) {
        assert age>0;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

My second attempt would constist of an interface and two classes:

```
/**
 * Anything with an age.
 */
interface HasAge {
    /**
     * @return the age
     */
    int getAge();
}



/**
 * A Person has name, gender, address etc
 */
class Person {
}


/**
 * A Person with a fixed age.
 */
class PersonWithAge extends Person implements HasAge{
    private final int age;

    PersonWithAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you implement an interface for this? Also, `assert` statements are usually ignored by the JVM unless you are running with assertions enabled (which you aren't in production)

Answer (score -1):

As others have noted, there could be problems, but it depends on the context. There are cases where the pattern above could be primarily beneficial.

1. There were mentions to use language supported exception handing, but a) not all languages have them or the coder may not know how to use them properly, b) exception handling may introduce too much overhead for the given scenario (just like there are cases where it could to the contrary improve performance).
2. The pattern may slow run-time performance, but it may improve it. First, in some languages, you can get compilers to compile the else statement similar to the pattern or vice-versa; however, it does on first sight appear that pattern may slow things down, so a compiler may not do it and it may not remove it either. And not all language environments have compilers. This means there are cases where only by avoiding that pattern (or putting it in by hand) could you improve performance. Let's see for a moment some reasons why the pattern (without else) could improve performance. A: For interpretive scenarios, cutting back on the number of language tokens, all else being equal, would shave time off the clock. B: For various reasons, there are many cpus that perform worse generally the more branching that exists in the machine instructions. The reason is that oftentimes the pipelines have to be flushed when branches are taken. There are predictive branching algorithms embedded inside the cpu. In some cases these could even have a particular branch improve performance, but generally you want to cut back on the number of branches you have in tight loops as a way to increase performance (and the pattern above fulfills that requirement). Sometimes cutting out branches can be had for free, but, as with this pattern, you can incur a cost, such as extra times setting the variable. However, if the extra writes happen infrequently enough, those costs could be overcome by the decrease in branches. Generally, though, you leave that kind of testing until the end. Unless you anticipate otherwise for a given case, that pattern is more likely than not to worsen performance or more likely just have no practical performance effect one way or the other.
3. Code readability: It could be cleaner to apply the pattern or not. It depends on the specific case. As was stated in the question, it does appear to cut back on the amount of code. That and having one fewer indentation layer could make a particular section of code look more organized and easier to follow.
4. More correct program: As was stated in one of the suggested answers, you may prefer to find bugs as early as possible in the design stages; however, not all programming tasks have the time in the world. Under times stresses, sometimes programming with extra layers of protection can solve the needed problem quickest with fewest problems. The greater chance of introducing or hiding hard-to-detect bugs might just be deemed less important at the moment that avoiding the negative effects of other bugs. In the given case, making sure "age" is set in this section of the code might be very important and by setting it early and in a single place, you could avoid potential future missteps during the addition of extra or longer branches which fail in some part to guarantee "age" is set.
5. Some of the complaints were against assumptions made about the code used in the question (what does "age" represent, what is the average case, etc), but at a more fundamental level, the question was about a general practice so those complaints are not complaints against the pattern.
6. For code you are writing for your own use or where you are the only one managing the code, what suits you best is possibly just what might be best, when we consider your overall productivity.
7. As we move into a world where robots and computers become more adept than humans at creative tasks and pose an increasing threat of one day enslaving humans, code written that simply fails to follow patterns or to use the features of a language to clarify intent may end up being a key defense for humans. I suggest as cheap insurance that some of this style of code be sprinkled here and there. For those times, I would follow the pattern for some of the code and not follow it in other places. [This may also come in handy if you fear being displaced in your job, but it may backfire. You have been warned.]

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! Please take a moment to read over the how-to guide for [answering questions](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Specifically, please try to contribute something new in an answer and not simply borrow from all other answers. As an aside, I don't think performance or robots are of much concern in this question.

Comment: a number of points i mentioned were not mentioned elsewhere. in particular the discussion on performance and on how time constraints/avoidance of particular bugs can make this pattern superior (eg, it's clear in setting variable). I referenced other comments to add continuity and context (point/counterpoint) and I recognized their value but showed alternative scenarios exist where they may not apply. [whole post was on providing scenarios missed by other comments]. I still hope this comment is valuable to at least some other readers for the new observations it makes and the light touch at end.

Answer (score -2):

An example where this can go terribly wrong: you have multiple threads which may have access to a variable `foo`. Imagine a situation where you first set `foo` to the else-value in thread 1. Then the CPU gets handed to thread 2 which reads the wrong value from `foo` before thread 1 is able to set the correct one.

Of course there are a lot of ways to avoid this, but let's be honest - everyone makes mistakes. And when the mistake is using a slightly wrong value in a complex calculation, well, good luck debugging.

Bonus information: both C++ and Java (and other languages?) allow you to just omit the curly brackets around the else for a single statement, eg:

```
if (foo) 
    bar = 1;
else
    bar = 2;
```

Comment: Using an `if-else` statement does not make code less susceptible to threading bugs. Also, I strongly recommend against omitting curly braces - that can be an easy source of hard-to-find bugs if you're not careful.

Comment: @Drascam you can always do `bar = foo? 1: 2;`. Hurray for ternaries

Comment: The code in the question is written in a constructor, the object is not available until the constructor has finished as long as it is not leaked from the constructor, which it isn't in this case.